# LFTP mirror replaces newer files with older ones?

Tags: ftp

Did I read this correctly in the [LFTP man page](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) for the `mirror` command?

> --only-newer  turns  off  file size comparison and uploads/downloads only newer files even if
>      size is different. By default older files are transferred and replace newer ones.

By default, if I issue the command `mirror / /local/folder`, which mirrors the remote site to my local folder, it will replace my local file with a remote file if it is **older** than my local file?

Is this actually what LFTP does? Is that not backwards to what's useful?

Answer (score 5):

You are correct in your understanding: by default, `mirror` will attempt to overwrite files -- even newer files -- with whatever you're downloading (or uploading, in the case of `mirror -R`).

```
Is that not backwards to what's useful?
```

It depends on your point of view.  The idea of `mirror`-ing is to make an *exact* duplicate of the remote files/directories, regardless of what changes may have been made to the local files since the last time `mirror` was executed.

See also the `xfer:clobber` setting if you want a blunter way of ignoring all possible overwrite conflicts.